# Proof from Holt's Linear Algebra and its Application Textbook

Tags: linear-algebra

I was having trouble figuring out the proof for the following question:

Let $\{u_1, u_2,...,u_m\}$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $m < n$, then this set does not span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have tried various examples and created augmented matrices for the examples and I've noticed that the last row is always a row of zeros. This indicates that the matrix does not have pivot points in every row which means that the set does not span $\mathbb{R}^n$. The only issue I have is that I don't know how to show this rigorously. I started learning Lin Alg yesterday so a little help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my version of the book you are using, Theorem 2.8 shows that $\langle u_1,\ldots,u_m\rangle = \Bbb{R}^n$ iff a row echelon form of the matrix whose columns are the $u_i$ has a pivot in each row. A matrix with $m$ columns can have at most $m$ pivots, so if $m < n$ then there can't possibly be $n$ pivots.

Comment: Ohhh! I see now. I completely forgot about the rule about $m$ columns and $m$ pivots. Thank you so much!